# Google App Script, Remove Document Sharing Permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Delete sharing permission for a user from a document ACL using URLFetchApp...

Below is my code

```
    function removeSharing(docId,userToRemove)
    {
      var base = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/';
      var fetchArgs = googleOAuthDeleteUser_('docs', base);
      var url = base+'private/full/'+docId+'/acl/'+encodeURIComponent(userToRemove);
      var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText(); 
      return 'ok';
    }
    function googleOAuthDeleteUser_(name,scope) {
        var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
        oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+encodeURIComponent(scope));
        oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
        oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
        oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
        oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

        return {
                oAuthServiceName:name, 
                oAuthUseToken:"always",
                headers : {
                           "GData-Version": "3.0",
                           "If-Match":"*"
                }, 
                method : "DELETE",
                contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
    }
```

It is Giving me error

> Request failed for returned code 400. Server response: GData`InvalidEntryException`The
>   posted entry is missing one or more of the required field(s):
>   scope

Please help in sorting this out.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#removing_sharing_permissions), your parameters should look like:

```
DELETE https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/acl/user:new_writer@example.com
```

If userToRemove has an e-mail address only, then this is probably the missing scope.